# Bash can't find file after I've moved it

Tags: bash, cache

After I move an executable file which I've recently executed (or more commonly, after I uninstall something from somewhere and install a different version somewhere else), bash can't find it, even if it's still on the PATH.

Example:

```
find
sudo mv /usr/bin/find /usr/local/bin
find
```

Results in:

```
bash: /usr/bin/find: No such file or directory
```

This is really annoying because it's happened to me dozens of times. How can I stop this happening?

Comment: Which file, where was it, where is it now, what permissions does it have, what command did you use to move it, what is your current $PATH.  Please provide significantly more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the problem permanently without disabling hashing entirely, put this in your bashrc:

```
shopt -s checkhash
```

See my other answer for how to solve the immediate problem.

Answer (score 6):

To clear the immediate problem:

```
hash -r
```

To stop it happening again:

```
set +h
```

to disable hashing (i.e. in-memory caching).

This can be put in a bash startup file such as `/etc/bashrc`.

The downside of this solution is that it slows things down a little if you have slow network filesystem(s) mounted and on the PATH.

Really, in my opinion, this is an ancient bash bug which should have been fixed years ago, and this is just a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

This can happen if the new copy isn't executable, so have a look at its permissions and ensure they're correct.